# submit form using a link but isset won't work

Tags: php, javascript, forms, isset

I have a form which is submitted using a link. However, when I try to use isset, it doesn't seem to work,

```
<form name="xForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="aff" class="make" value="" />
   <a href="#" title="" class="pay-button" style="margin-top:5px;" name="submit" onclick="document.xForm.submit()">SUBMIT</a>
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
          $aff = $_POST['aff'];
       }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: <a> is not a form element. I suggest change the <a> to a `<input type="submit"  name="submit">` or `<input type="image" name="submit">`

Comment: As stated in the answer from Shadow Wizard, using `name="submit"` anywhere is bound to cause trouble. It's not clear what you want to do with it, but you should use another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any form element named "submit".

Either add such as hidden input, or check the text box name:

```
if(isset($_POST['aff']))
```

The anchor name is not relevant.

<strike>The code for hidden input is:</strike>

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
```

Adding it to the form, you will get the value "true" when the form will be submitted.

The above (adding hidden input named *submit*) is not good idea as it will cause the code `ocument.xForm.submit()` to fail - if you choose hidden input just give it other name.

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['submit']` is not defined because the value of `<a>` is not passed by forms (doesn't matter if you put a name attribute on it).

Answer (score 0):

anchor tag is not form element so its values will not be available in $_POST variable. Removing the isset will work